# Parent process does not catch all his child processes

Tags: c++, c, process, fork, zombie-process

I have following problem:

I have main (parent) procces, which creates another processes (childs) using fork function. I am catching child's status to eliminate zombies. When there is 1 child process, it is catched correctly, but when there are more processes (aprx. 30) created by parent process, there are aprx. 4 zombies left = parent does not catch all the children (return status/state = <defunct>).

Child status is catched using

```
void selfkill(int status) {
    wait(&status);
}

signal(SIGCHLD, selfkill);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably use [`waitpid()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) with WNOHANG in a loop inside the signal handler.

What probably happens is that not all the signals are delivered - because some of them arrive too close to each other.  You could perhaps alleviate that problem by using [`sigaction()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) instead of [`signal()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html), too.